# Ubuntu 16.04 - installing Dlink WiFi drivers for DWA-131 E1

Tags: drivers, wireless, 16.04

I need to install drivers for the aforementioned device on 16.04 asap. None of the other threads are helping I.e. there's always an error message in the terminal. Any help?
P.S I'm a complete Linux noob, so bear with me please

```
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 2001:3319 D-Link Corp.
```

thats the lsusb entry for my dongle

Comment: What have you tried? What error are you getting? Can you post the log and errors?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lsusb` terminal command.

Comment: Well, I've tried all the tricks by now. Installed ndisgtk and added the drivers too, but to no avail.then tried the setup for windows through wine. Again, nothing. Now clean reinstall and beginning again. Lsusb recognised it, iwconfig says no wireless extensions. Additional drivers doesn't show this at all

Comment: I'm on my phone so I can't display outputs. Plus it was never recognised as a wireless device or as a usb

Comment: Do you mean that `lsusb` doesn't show your device *at all*? Without some details, we cannot help you.

Comment: Bus 003 Device 002: ID 2001:3319 D-Link Corp. 

thats the lsusb entry for my dongle

Comment: http://www.linux-hardware-guide.com/in/2013-11-16-d-link-dwa-131-n300-usb-wifi-adapter                                                                                     i followed their instructions for the E1 architecture but the make command resulted in "error"'s highlighted in red all over the place

Comment: Okay, I've given up on the dongle. Any plug and play WiFi dongles for Xenial ?

Answer (score 2):

I added the [2001:3319] ID to Realtek USB driver and it works.

Install it for Xenial this way:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:hanipouspilot/rtlwifi
sudo apt update
sudo apt install rtl8192eu-dkms
```