# Wifi-driver not working Lenovo z51-70

Tags: drivers, wireless, 16.04, lenovo

```
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation Device [14e4:43ae] (rev 02)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device [17aa:0622]
```

Comment: how should i proceed on installing the required drivers ?

Comment: The problem is to find drivers for this adapter if any exist.

Comment: using which code in this should i search for the driver ?

Comment: It looks like there is no linux driver for this adapter.

Comment: i even got wireless adapter d-link dwa131 E1 ver:5.01 and tried loads of stuffs but the wifi adapter is also not working !

Comment: I made a working driver for  d-link dwa131 E1. If you ask a new question regarding this adapter, I will give directions how to install it. Please add output of `lsusb` to that new answer.

Comment: See http://askubuntu.com/q/780202/167850

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/792773/dlink-dwa-131-h-w-ver-e1-f-w-ver-5-1-how-do-i-install-its-wifi-driver-in-ubu

the link to my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This adapter is not supported by any existing Linux drivers so far.