# DLink dwa 131 H/W ver :E1 F/W ver : 5.1 how do i install it's wifi driver in UBUNTU 16.04

Tags: wireless, 16.04, lenovo, ubuntu-drivers, lsusb

The wifi adapter doesnt work on my laptop lenovo Z51 UBUNTU 16.04 info about the adapter
DLink dwa 131 H/W ver :E1 F/W ver : 5.1

lsusb

```
 Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8001 Intel Corp. 
 Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
 Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
 Bus 002 Device 005: ID 0489:e079 Foxconn / Hon Hai 
 Bus 002 Device 004: ID 5986:0670 Acer, Inc 
 Bus 002 Device 003: ID 0bda:0129 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5129    Card Reader Controller
 Bus 002 Device 002: ID 2001:3319 D-Link Corp. 
 Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can install a driver for Ubuntu 16.04 this way

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:hanipouspilot/rtlwifi
sudo apt update
sudo apt install rtl8192eu-dkms
```

You need to be connected by wire for that.

This is my PPA. I added the ID for this adapter to official Realtek drivers. They always forget to do it.

If UEFI is used in your computer, you need to disable SecureBoot to load the kernel module.

Comment: i have tried this once even i tried it once again

Comment: What do you mean you tried? You need to use only one solution, not many. They conflict. This driver should work. Maybe you installed another driver from the same PPA or a driver from git. You need to remove everything else.

Comment: how do i remove the ones i have already installed ?

Comment: It depends on what did you install. To start please give output of `dkms status`.

Comment: 8192cu, 1.10, 4.4.0-21-generic, x86_64: installed |||||

rtl8192eu, 4.3.8.12406.20140929~xenial2, 4.4.0-21-generic, x86_64: installed|||||

rtl8192eu, 4.3.8.12406.20140929~xenial2, 4.4.0-28-generic, x86_64: installed

Comment: Remove `8192cu` by `sudo dkms remove 8192cu/1.10 --all`, then run `sudo modprobe rtl8192eu` and insert the dongle. It should work.

Comment: my current dkms status
rtl8192eu, 4.3.8.12406.20140929~xenial2, 4.4.0-21-generic, x86_64: installed ||||||
rtl8192eu, 4.3.8.12406.20140929~xenial2, 4.4.0-28-generic, x86_64: installed

Comment: it says modprobe: FATAL: Module rtl8192eu not found in directory /lib/modules/4.4.0-28-generic

Comment: Oops. Hold on, I will check the driver.

Comment: The correct name is `8192eu`. Run `sudo modprobe 8192eu` and test.

Comment: modprobe: ERROR: could not insert '8192eu': Required key not available

Comment: Oh, this can be easily fixed. Disable SecureBoot in BIOS. The module is not signed and SecureBoot does not let to load it.

Comment: how do i disable secure boot ?

Comment: Just disable SecureBoot and the issue will be fixed.

Comment: Ok got it i will run my BIOS and come back

Comment: Thanx thanx a lot ..is there any way i can give u 10-15 green ticks and 20-30 upvotes :P

Comment: No, please do not do it. This is not allowed and will be automatically reverted including the fair one.

Comment: just kidding :P

Comment: how do i start learning about ubuntu like installing these things kernels etc etc ?

Comment: Use Ubuntu, ask questions, find answers, etc.